# Interacting with text in Django for loop

Tags: javascript, django, tippyjs

I am working on a Django project where I want to output a text file and apply certain operations like highlighting to the text. My idea was to implement it in such a way that each word can be clicked, for a popup window (or tooltip window) to appear, displaying all the options.

```
{% for Line in File.body %}
<div>
    {% for Token in Line %}
      {% if not Token.content == None %}
        <span class="inline token" id="token">
          <strong style="color: {{ Token.highlight }};">
            {{ Token.content }}
          </strong>
        </span>
        <div id="{{ Token.unique_id }}">
          POPUP </br>
          <button onclick="changeColor()">Highlight</button>
        </div>

        <script>
          tippy('.token', {
            content: document.getElementById("{{ Token.unique_id }}"),
            delay: 100,
            arrow: true,
            arrowType: 'round',
            size: 'large',
            duration: 500,
            animation: 'scale',
            allowHTML: true,
            hideOnClick: true,
            trigger: "click"
          })

          function changeColor() {
          var token = document.getElementById("token");
          token.style.color="blue;";

          }
      </script>

      {% endif %}
      {% if Token.endline %}
          </br>
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</div>

{% endfor %}
```

I tried using the tippjs tooltip library (https://atomiks.github.io/tippyjs/), but clicking the highlight button doesn't do anything. If i don't put the javascript part in the loop, nothing happens at all. The code with the javascript part not in the loop would look something like this:

```
<script>
    tippy('.token', {
        content: document.getElementById("{{ Token.unique_id }}"),
        delay: 100,
        arrow: true,
        arrowType: 'round',
        size: 'large',
        duration: 500,
        animation: 'scale',
        allowHTML: true,
        hideOnClick: true,
        trigger: "click"
      })

      function changeColor() {
      var token = document.getElementById("token");
      token.style.color="blue;";
      }
  </script>

{% for Line in File.body %}
<div>
    {% for Token in Line %}
      {% if not Token.content == None %}
        <span class="inline token" id="token">
          <strong style="color: {{ Token.highlight }};">
            {{ Token.content }}
          </strong>
        </span>
        <div id="{{ Token.unique_id }}">
          POPUP </br>
          <button onclick="changeColor()">Highlight</button>
        </div>

      {% endif %}
      {% if Token.endline %}
          </br>
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</div>

{% endfor %}
```

I am new to django and even newer to javascript, so I'm not sure if this is even the right way to go about this.

Can somebody point me in the right direction here?

Comment: Can you show code, when you try without put js in part in the loop?